# switchable python server client

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, network-programming

I am trying to make a python program which when switched on acts as a client and detects the presence of any servers around it for 15 secs. If it doesn't find any, it promotes itself to a server and broadcasts its own ip as a HOST.

```
#RECIEVE
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('',37885))
s.settimeout(15)
HOST=s.recvfrom(1024)
s.settimeout(None)
print HOST[0]

#BROADCAST 
if (len(HOST)==0):
    HOST = gethostbyname(gethostname())
    print (HOST)
    for i in range(10):
        s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        s.sendto(str(HOST),('255.255.255.255',37885))
        time.delay(1)
```

The problem I am facing is that the program quits as soon as it doesn't find any servers. I need to have a switchable server and client configuration. How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: This is really not a good use of broadcast. If you really only want to deal with a subset of all the hosts on a network, you should use multicast.

Comment: You seem to be saying that the problem is that your program quits. You can rectify that by simply *not* quitting. You need to provide a better problem description if you want useful suggestions.

Comment: It was a case of simple exception handling. Used try and except method to solve the current problem.